# Wicket: Check if some specific button was clicked?

Tags: java, wicket

Some info about our application:

- Center layout: a panel to display some items
- Right layout: a panel to edit selected item
- Top layout: some buttons: `Button1` | `Button2` | `Button3`

Expected: When editing an object, if `Button1` or `Button2` is clicked -> display confirmation dialog to make sure the user really wants to leave current editing.

Is there a generic way (because we will have many more buttons in the future) to check whether `Button1` or `Button2` was clicked?

Comment: if you want to capture the button click, then addClickHandlers for both the buttons and set the boolean variable to true inside the click handler. Make sure boolean variable have the object scope.

Comment: Hello! I edited your question to make it more clear what you want to achieve. If you have more details, such as the code you are using, please edit your question to add it!

Answer (score 0):

If those are normal (i.e. non-Ajax) buttons then use something like:

```
button.add(AttributeModifier.append("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure?')"));
```

If they are Ajax buttons/links then you will need to use AjaxCallListener with a precondition. See https://github.com/martin-g/blogs/blob/c29f0875910d3bd5e11bca0d2c0fa8cdd84e3736/wicket6-ajax-demo/src/main/java/com/wicketinaction/HandlebarsButton.java#L110 and http://wicketinaction.com/2012/07/wicket-6-javascript-improvements/